# Why am I getting 32767 after each output in the following code?

Tags: c++

```cpp
const bool ASCENDING = 0;
const bool DESCENDING = 1;

int sortDigit(int number, bool order)
{

    if (order == ASCENDING && number > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            for (int j = number; j > 0; j /= 10)
            {
                if (j % 10 == i)
                {
                    cout << i;
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
        }
    }

    if (order == DESCENDING && number > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (int j = number; j > 0; j /= 10)
            {
                if (j % 10 == i)
                {
                    cout << i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "sortDigit(54321, ASCENDING) = " << sortDigit(54321, ASCENDING) << endl;
}
```

The code is supposed to sort numbers in arranging or descending order.
Every time I run it, after arranging the numbers in desired order the output is followed by 32767
Ex:-
sortDigit(54321, ASCENDING)
output:- 1234532767

Comment: The shown code in this question fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone on stackoverflow.com can determine the problem. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @OP What is the original question you're trying to solve?  Just showing us code and saying "it does this, and is wrong" is not a question.  We don't know what your program is supposed to do.

Comment: @Pete Backer thx I missed that :-)

Comment: what happened when you debugged the code? `32767` is `0x7FFF`, look for that value somewhere in your code

Comment: code works correctly: https://godbolt.org/z/a5rcDL something else in your code is printing that value, please provide a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles Is it because I am using it as a function without any return?

Comment: possibly, if you give a [mre] we might be able to tell you. lacking a return statement does mean your program has undefined behaviour

Comment: That's definitely the problem. Your function isn't returning a value. If you want it to return something, you need to specify what. If you don't want it to return something, don't call it as part of `std::cout <<`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
cout << "sortDigit(54321, ASCENDING) = " << sortDigit(54321, ASCENDING) << endl;
```

Your function `sortDigit()` has no return value, so your code has undefined behaviour, in your case it prints 32767, in mine 0.

`12345` is the orderded number which is printed out in your function, followed by the undefined value printed in `main()`.

If you do just:

```
int main() {
    sortDigit(54321, ASCENDING);
}
```

You will have the correct output.

[**Live sample**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qZpXnRyjW0OoYGx2)

If you have that option it would be simpler to use `std::sort` form the `<algorithm>` standard library:

```
int arr[] = { 4,6,9,4,2,1 };

sort(&arr[0], &arr[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])]); // ascending

sort(&arr[0], &arr[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])], greater<int>()); //descending
```

[**Live Sample**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tLrwXsAcGidvk4PY)

Using C++ standard containers like `std::vector` or `std::array` is also advised.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But am actually not supposed to use arrays or any other libraries except <math.h>

Comment: @ParamKhurana, I suspected as much, then just correct the return problem as I described and you will be all set, unless you have to return the sorted array, in that case you will have to return the array and assign it to a main variable, or, alternatively, pass it by reference to the function.

Comment: @ParamKhurana, glad to help, don't forget to [accept one of the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `sortDigit()` is already printing out the output.  You don't need to send the return value of `sortDigit()`, declared as an `int`, to `cout` too.

This is what you see after the output of `sortDigit()`.  The `<<` operators to `cout` are processed from left to right.  First the initial constant text is printed out.  Then `sortDigit()` is called to get its return value and it prints out some text.  Then the return value of `sortDigit()` is printed.  That's the 32767.

You aren't actually returning anything from `sortDigit()` (where is the return statement?), so you basically get a random value.  The proper term is undefined behavior.

Turning on compiler warnings, and paying attention to them, is good idea.  They will catch this stuff.

```
<source>: In function 'int sortDigit(int, bool)':    
<source>:32:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]    
   32 | }    
      | ^
```